# Rename file Which is already uploaded

Tags: php, mysql, rename, file-rename

I have already use upload & show function in PHP, but if someone press "Rename" button in my view section, it will open a dialog box where existing filename show, it can be changed by user & also store the new name which is input by the user(not only in SQL but also changed file name which is stored directory).
file path stored in MySQL, files store in define folder.

I tried to find on the internet but most of its change the name while uploading or change the pre define names, not change by the user

Here is my file uploading code:

```
 $db=connection
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {

     $filename=$_FILES["pdf"]["name"];
     $tempname=$_FILES["pdf"]["tmp_name"];
     $folder="files/".$filename;

     move_uploaded_file($tempname,$folder);
     $abc="INSERT INTO tables (pdf) VALUES ('$folder')";
     $res=mysqli_query($db,$abc);
  if($res)
  {
   echo "save";
  }
 }
```

& this is my view:

```
<?php

$acb = "SELECT * FROM tables";
$ress = mysqli_query($db, $acb);
while ($test = mysqli_fetch_array($ress)) {
    $id = $test['id'];
    echo "<tr alian='center'>";

    $path = "/files";
    $file2 = basename($path, ".php");
    echo "<td>".$test['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".basename($test['pdf'])."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href='ren.php?id=$id'>Rename</a></td>";

    echo "<td><a href='del.php?id=$id'>Delete</a> 
</td>";
}
```

I understand that this is simple code & not have any related code for renaming, but I already tried many times for check.

Comment: Please provide the existing code to your `move_uploaded_file()` routine.  It's fine that it's not working.  We just need to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Typically one would use - `rename($src,$dest)` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php - and then probably you will need `direname($file)` and then update of the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a different approach here: Maybe upload the files and rename them to something convenient after upload, for example: id of table's row, and store the name of the file in your MySQL table (add a filename column), which the user can change.
Then when the user downloads the file, send the name stored in the database with the `Content-disposition` header.

On upload:

```
$filename = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, basename($_FILES["pdf"]["name"]));

if (mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tables (pdf) VALUES ('$filename')")) {
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
    $folder = "files/" . $id;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdf"]["tmp_name"], $folder);
}
```

When updating the filename, you will do something like this:

```
UPDATE tables SET pdf = '$newName' WHERE id = $id
```

(Don't forget to escape the input and sanitize the filename)

When serving the file to the user (user downloads the file)

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $row["filename"] . '"');
readfile('files/' . $row["id"]);
```